# Drupal Leaflet - How to hide markers and disable clusters on click

Tags: drupal, leaflet

I want to be able to disable/hide all other markers and marker clusters when the "show on map" link is clicked for one location. This means that whenever a location link is clicked, only that active location should display. I'm using the leaflet drupal module and a view to create and display the map and associated items.

[This is what the frontend looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYbAB.png)

This is my code:

```
         if ($('#' + mapId).length) {
            var locationMap = drupalSettings.leaflet[mapId];

            // init object to hold marker ids and latlng values
            var locationMarkers = {};

            // Generating the data for each marker
            function markerReference(cLid, cMarker) {
              locationMarkers[cLid] = {};
              locationMarkers[cLid].id = cLid;
              locationMarkers[cLid].marker = cMarker;
            }

            // Generating the data for each marker
            $.each(locationMap.markers, function (id, data) {
              markerReference(id.replace("-0", ""), data);
            });

            // Show marker on map click, zoom to marker and open popup
            $('.show-on-map').click(function (e) {
              e.preventDefault();

              let currentLid = $(this).data('lid');
              let locationMarker = locationMarkers[currentLid].marker;
              $('.ab-c-location[data-lid=' + currentLid + ']').addClass('current-location');

              lMap.setView(locationMarker._latlng, 10);
              setTimeout(function() { locationMarker.openPopup(); }, 280);
            });
          }
```

I've tried simply hiding them with CSS, but when you zoom out enough for the marker clusters to activate, it clears/breaks it. I feel like the marker clusters are in the way but I'm not exactly sure how to fix this.

I also tried iterating through the markers and hiding them with .removeLayer() but that didn't seem to work fully because markers within the clusters wouldn't hide. Maybe this means I need a way to disable to clusters first and then remove each layer?

Does anyone have any suggestions?